# Can I steal a vim session from another terminal?

Tags: linux, vim, gnu-screen

I forgot to start `screen` before I started working, and now I've SSH'd into my machine from my laptop. `ps -a` gives me the process ID of the vim process. Can I steal the vim session from my other terminal and attach it to my ssh session?

Comment: kill it and recover the swap file (`vi -r filename`) could be ok for you?

Answer (score 12):

The [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) program would allow you to do that.

Comment: this thing really works!

Answer (score 1):

You could save the vim session using `:mksession ~/session.vim`, and reload it in screen using `vim -S ~/session.vim`.

`:mksession` essentially saves the current vim session as a file that you can pass around between terminals, or re-open once you have shut your computer down, etc.

Comment: Actually, if you have the clientserver option built into your executable, you should be able to remotely send the commands that @Pascal mentions to save off the running session and then close it out.  You could then restore it in the term. that you are in.

See ':h remote_send()'

Comment: This works without the need to install another program. Great solution