# Is there any simple tmux/screen alternative?

Tags: ssh, terminal, vim, tmux

I would like to connect to a terminal session/application running on different computer but without usage of terminal multiplexer as tmux or screen. I don't need split windows or sharing the terminal with others. I also had troubles with colors and other things when running tmux/screen with vim.

In other words: I just need to reconnect to my vim through ssh but as simple as possible without thinking about it ahead.  I don't need another layer of keyboard mappings…

Is there any way how to do it?

Comment: [See this](http://superuser.com/q/544154/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Thanks, it looks usable for me…

Comment: you can copy and paste the answer and answer your own question with the comment. That will help others if they look at this question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dtach is a program written in C that emulates the detach feature of screen

https://github.com/crigler/dtach

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you expand your answer a bit? Just pointing to a product doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution. It's better to include some instructions on how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution, providing value beyond a random Google hit. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deal with unreliable connections, try `mosh`:

https://mosh.org/

If you just want more terminal sessions and detach/reattach, try `byobu`:

https://www.byobu.org/

For a possibly simpler multiplexer, try `dvtm`:

https://www.brain-dump.org/projects/dvtm/

Answer (score 0):

Another option written in Rust is`zellij`: https://github.com/zellij-org/zellij

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).